# React-Native NFC Reader returns: The NFC tag's type is not supported

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-nfc-manager

I am trying to create an android app that will be used to make a payment with an Ingenico terminal. I added the react-native-nfc-manager (https://github.com/whitedogg13/react-native-nfc-manager) to my project an followed the v2-ios+android-write-ndef example. I also enabled NFC on my phone. I bought from Amazon an NFC USB reader. I installed it and also got a windows app called GoToTags that connected successfully to the USB module.

I fired up my app and tested the NFC button.

The scanner beeps (So the NFC technologie was loaded) but GoToTags sends back a message (The NFC tag's type is not supported) that looks like this:

```
{"Uid":null,"ReadOnly":false,"DataLength":null,"CanMakeReadOnly":false,
"Formatted":false,"Records":null,"TagTech":null,"MaxDataLength":null,
"Exception":"The NFC tag's type is not supported."}
```

I am unsure what I am doing wrong. I followed the instructions to the letter and also watched and followed a YouTube tutorial.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kx22B6OH3Oc

The only difference between my code and the guy in the YouTube video is that I am using an android phone instead of an iPhone.

This is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { 
  View,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';
import NfcManager, {Ndef, NfcTech} from 'react-native-nfc-manager';

function buildUrlPayload(valueToWrite) {
    return Ndef.encodeMessage([
        Ndef.uriRecord(valueToWrite),
    ]);
}

class AppV2Ndef extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    NfcManager.start();
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this._cleanUp();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{padding: 20}}>
        <Text>NFC Demo</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity 
          style={{padding: 10, width: 200, margin: 20, borderWidth: 1, borderColor: 'black'}}
          onPress={this._testNdef}
        >
          <Text>Test Ndef</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>

        <TouchableOpacity 
          style={{padding: 10, width: 200, margin: 20, borderWidth: 1, borderColor: 'black'}}
          onPress={this._cleanUp}
        >
          <Text>Cancel Test</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    )
  }

  _cleanUp = () => {
    NfcManager.cancelTechnologyRequest().catch(() => 0);
  }

  _testNdef = async () => {
    try {
      let resp = await NfcManager.requestTechnology(NfcTech.Ndef, {
        alertMessage: 'Ready to write some NFC tags!'
      });
      console.warn(resp);
      let ndef = await NfcManager.getNdefMessage();
      console.warn(ndef);
      let bytes = buildUrlPayload('https://www.google.com');
      await NfcManager.writeNdefMessage(bytes);
      console.warn('successfully write ndef');
      await NfcManager.setAlertMessageIOS('I got your tag!');
      this._cleanUp();
    } catch (ex) {
      console.warn('ex', ex);
      this._cleanUp();
    }
  }
}

export default AppV2Ndef;
```

What I need to do is send out a 4 digit code to the Ingenico terminal from the phone using the NFC tech. But before I go a head an make that possible, I just want to get the NFC to work first. Sending out https://google.com to the card reader would be a good first step. But so fare, no luck.

What am I missing? It seems pretty much straight forward no?